# Configure apache to be accessible over port 1234 in the directory /wiki

Tags: linux, apache, unix

I have some work that I want to get done, and it's to use the apache webserver. Configure apache to be accessible over port 1234 in the directory /wiki. I.e. access with http ://YouIP:1234/wiki.

So far, this is what I've done
I made apache so that it can be used through the port. This was done by reversing the proxy server. This was achieved by making a file that can be accessed within the apache file. The contents of the file are as follows:

```
<Location /wiki> 
ProxyPass https://localhost:1234 
ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:1234 
</Location>
```

However, when I did this, I was careful when I did this step as the service needed some rudimentary support for this kind of setup: if it returns HTML pages with links in it, it won't assume anymore that http ://localhost/i/index.php is the correct URL to tell the client. httpd will not look into the returned content and will rewrite it.

Comment: Why is there a `ProxyPass` directive involved here? This does not match the question you ask. If you want to make the apache server listen to port 1234, then you have to use its `Listen` directive. Otherwise apache will listen on the standard http/https ports, which are 80/443. The `ProxyPass` directive serves completely different purposes, none of which I can spot in the question...

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to set apache to listen on port 1234 instead of 80.
then you do not need a reverse proxy.
search you Listen directive on apache config file (redhat/centos : /etc/httpd, debian/ubuntu : /etc/apache2)

If you want the url to contain /wiki/, simply put your file under a directory named wiki under your document root (/var/www or /var/www/html)
You can easilly redirect request to your root to /wiki/ via .htaccess file or a simple ans small php redirect file in this way:

```
<?php
header("Location: /wiki/");
?>
```